# Why did meat and dairy drop out of the working people in Britain's diet during the industrial enclosures period?

Tags: united-kingdom, social-history, food, social-class

During the industrial enclosures period (1750-1832) meats and dairy dropped out of the diet of working people in Britain.  This change was regional (oatmeal regions maintained milk consumption, bread regions didn't, Irish migratory labour didn't).  What caused this dietary change?

Sources: Hammond & Hammond, Labourers series (Village, Town, Skilled).

Answer (score 4):

Rural workers at one point lived with the framer and ate at his table, food & lodgings being a large part of the wage. There was a shift to just money wages, and a bit class difference that farmers no longer would eat with their labourers. So originally the workers received payment in kind that included meat and later they had to buy the meat.